# php clear text printed to webpage

Tags: php, html, refresh

I have a html/php script which prints a text string directly to the page. However when I refresh the page that text is still there. I've googled this and check this forum too and tried various suggestions e.g.

```
<input autocomplete="off">
```

and

```
<body onload="document.FormName.reset();">
```

etc. None of them work.

The php code that prints the string is (if regex matches serial number then execute command else print error string):

```
if (preg_match($snregex, $sn, $matches)) {
  <command>
} else {
  echo "Invalid SN. Please re-enter!";
}
```

Should I print the string using a different way that can be cleared on refresh?

Comment: Could you share code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (preg_match($snregex, $sn, $matches)) {
 <command>
} else {
  //echo "Invalid SN. Please re-enter!";
 }
```

try commenting the echo and check if the text is still there.

if not, every time the else loop gets executed and prints the statement.

**solution:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && (preg_match($snregex, $sn, $matches))
{
 <command>
} else {
  echo "Invalid SN. Please re-enter!";
 }
```

Comment: is the text gets printed in your page or in a text field??

Comment: Looks like that was it. Commenting it out removed it.

Comment: use the condition inside a submit event or so, it won't print unless its executed... SEE SOLUTION...

Answer (score 0):

Is it printing out from a session or post var that's not getting cleared ? is the input field something like

```
input value="<?php if(isset($_POST['serial_number'])){echo S_POST['serial_number'];}?>"
```