# php variable out of scope when using $_POST

Tags: php, variables, post, scope, global

I have variables $a and $location. However when I press the 'Submit' button the variable has gone out of scope. I can pass in in the variable from input box T2 but I can't manage to manage to do it to 'a' which is a regular variable. I added echo $b to debug it and I do get that output which verifies the conditional statement is true.

```
<?php
[...]

$a = '5';
$location = 'home';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $location=$_POST['T2'];
    echo $location;
    echo $a;
    $b = '6';
    echo $b;
    [...]
}
?>

<input type="text" name="T2" value="<?php echo $location; ?>">
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="create">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Is `$a` even defined?

Comment: did you forget to use hidden fields? You can't post vars unless there assigned to a hidden field.

Comment: What do you expect this snippet to do, and what does it actually do? This is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is just a snippet of my code. I omitted additional code to simply the code excerpt. I need to use both $location and $a.

Comment: @stevo You're going to have to show us more code then. This isn't enough to go on. It's anybody's guess. Plus, make sure your submit button's named and all elements are too.

Comment: @hd Yes $a is defined earlier on before the echo

Comment: a condition (if/else) structure doesnt create a new scope) it's not possible that the first $a and the 2nd $a have different values with above code unless $a is callable and even then.

Comment: And does `isset($_POST['submit'])` return true?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` would show you exactly what the script's receiving, and you'll probably find that the `<button>` isn't going out with the rest of the form. As for varaible scope - there is NO variable scope between script invocations. Once a php script shuts down and exists, all variables are destroyed and cleaned up.

Comment: `This is just a snippet of my code. I omitted additional code to simply the code excerpt. ` I bet that omitted code holds the key to this answer if, according to your update, the conditional statement is `true` :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Yeah, I'm thinking the same too. Your answer is correct as is mine which I posted after seeing OP's edit. If that is indeed most of actual code, it's obvious that is missing form tags and method. OP hasn't responded, so I'll just give up on the question and if OP wants to accept any which answer, good. Otherwise, OP's going to have to post **full/actual** code. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by echoing it in a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="myvar" value="<?php echo $a; ?>">
```

and then using $_POST to extract it

```
$a=$_POST['myvar'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a="Testing";
echo $a;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {         // you're not getting here
    $location=$_POST['T2'];     
    echo $a;
    echo "Testing one two three";    // even this won't show :)
}
```

There is only one plausible reason for that second echo not to work, i.e. Your `if` condition doesnt evaluate to true. There is no other reason that can cause that. Now check your field or button named `submit` on the form :)

A simple  `print_r($_POST);` will tell you all that was posted, you can check there if `submit` was also posted.

Comment: Well not really, the only way possible if there is no post with submit

Comment: That's the same statement in different words.

Comment: @DarkMukke Yes, if `isset($_POST['submit'])` doesn't return TRUE, then `$a` will never try and be echo'd.

Comment: he shouldnt check a field named 'submit' he should just check if it excists in the form

Comment: @DarkMukke You're just regurgitating the answer but in different words... And I don't think you even realise you are.

Comment: @DarkMukke That's not the question, Question is about OP's confusion about scope and mistakenly thinking the variable is being eaten alive by the scope. Im not going to teach then which variable to check the form for.

Answer (score 1):

Far as I can tell, you're missing the form tags along with the method which should be `post`, least from what you posted for code.

*Sidenote:* If what you posted isn't full code, do. The following works which printed `home56` on submit.

*I do believe that's what the expected result should be.*

```
<?php

$a = '5';
$location = 'home';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $location=$_POST['T2'];
    echo $location;
    echo $a;
    $b = '6';
    echo $b;

}
?>

<form action="" method = "post">
<input type="text" name="T2" value="<?php echo $location; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="create">

</form>
```

*Sidenote:* You can keep your present button if you wish instead of the input I tested with:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="create">Submit</button>
```

---

*Footnotes:*

Both `[...]` - any relevance? I'll bet there is.

Comment: I already had the following:
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="index.php">

Comment: @stevo My answer works. If it's still not working for you, then you have to show us full code. There's nothing more that Hanky or I can do without knowing what's in `[...]` or elsewhere.

Comment: @stevo Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, and use `var_dump();` on your variables. If you have any JS happening, let us know. You really need to post full code right up front, because it's guess work right off the bat and I don't deal with guesses, I deal with actuals. Had I known beforehand, I would not have submitted my answer.

Comment: @stevo From what I gather in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/26278179/ - you most likely do have JS happening `<body onload="document.FormName.reset();">` am I right on this one? Relevant?

Comment: @stevo Thanks, but there's no way I can test this. See if someone else picks up on the question.

Comment: I can get the code to work if I pass the value and not the variable i.e. $_POST['foo'] = 5 works but $_POST['foo'] = $a does not. However I do need to pass the variable name.